# How to make CheckBox as checked and unchecked so that user can modify it in Grid Control?

Tags: c#, checkbox, syncfusion, gridcontrol

I have designed a `grid control` with 20 rows and 3 columns.
In first column I have puted some hardcoded string and in second column I want to put `checkBox` with checked unchecked behavior so that user can modify it.I have written code for this in `QueryCellInfo` event in my below code but it is not working.

How do I complete it?

Kindly suggest.

**Below is My Part of code:**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer t1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    private Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.Grid.GridControl gridControlDownloadScript = new Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.Grid.GridControl();
    public Form1()
    {
       // this.gridControl1.GridVisualStyles = Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.GridVisualStyles.Metro;
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        gridControl1.Model.RowCount = 20;
        gridControl1.Model.ColCount = 3;
        this.gridControl1.VScrollPixel = true;
        this.gridControl1.HScrollPixel = true;


        this.gridControl1[0, 1].Text = "EMPLOYEE";
        this.gridControl1[0, 2].Text = "CHECKBOX";
        this.gridControl1[0, 3].Text = " ";
        this.gridControl1[1, 1].Text = "Rahul Verma";
        this.gridControl1[2, 1].Text = "MAnish Desai";
        this.gridControl1[3, 1].Text = "Mohan Pothala";
        this.gridControl1[4, 1].Text = "Dhanraj Dhoke";

        gridControl1.Model.RowCount = 20;

        gridControl1.Model.ColCount = 3;
        gridControl1.QueryCellInfo += new GridQueryCellInfoEventHandler(GridQueryCellInfo);
        gridControl1.SaveCellInfo += new GridSaveCellInfoEventHandler(GridSaveCellInfo);
        gridControl1.QueryRowCount += gridControl1_QueryRowCount;
        gridControl1.QueryColCount += gridControl1_QueryColCount;
        this.gridControl1.HScrollBehavior = GridScrollbarMode.Disabled; 
        this.gridControl1.VScrollBehavior = GridScrollbarMode.Disabled;

        this.gridControl1.ColWidths.ResizeToFit(GridRangeInfo.Cols(1, 1));

        this.gridControl1.RowHeights.ResizeToFit(GridRangeInfo.Rows(1, 20));


        t1.Interval = 250;

        t1.Tick += new EventHandler(IncreaseProgressBar);



    }

    private void CellClick(object sender, GridCellClickEventArgs e)
    {
    }



    private void IncreaseProgressBar(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Increment(5);
        progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
        progressBar1.Maximum = 100;


        lblProgress.Text = progressBar1.Value.ToString() + "%";

        if (progressBar1.Value == progressBar1.Maximum)

            t1.Stop();
    }

    private void gridControl1_QueryColCount(object sender, GridRowColCountEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void gridControl1_QueryRowCount(object sender, GridRowColCountEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void GridQueryCellInfo(object sender, GridQueryCellInfoEventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (i++ < 4)
        {
            if (i == 0 || i == 1 || i == 4 || i == 6 || i == 9 || i == 11 || i == 14)
            {

                continue;

            }
            else if (e.RowIndex == i && e.ColIndex == 2)
            {

                e.Style.CellType = GridCellTypeName.CheckBox;

                e.Style.Description = "";
        this.gridControl1[i, 2].CheckBoxOptions = new GridCheckBoxCellInfo("True", "False", string.Empty, false);
                e.Style.CheckBoxOptions.CheckedValue = "true";
                e.Style.CellValue = "true";

            }

        }
        if (e.RowIndex > 0 && e.ColIndex > 0)
        {


        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the technology you use? Win forms? WPF? Also what do you mean by "On demand" you just want user to modify them right?

Comment: @Emad , I am using win forms.yes,I want user to modify them.

Sorry for Confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually do this using grid properties define column properties manually set column as checkbox then it will behave as you want

Answer (score 0):

The **QueryCellInfo** event will trigger for every **cell** in the **GridControl**. As per your code, you have set the cell value to true in the QueryCellInfo event. So the **CellValue** of **CheckBox** will remains True for all the time. If you want user to modify the **CheckedValue** set the CellValue for that particular cell as “*True*” in Form_Load() method. Please refer the below code,
Code snippet
    this.gridControl1[2, 2].CellValue = "True";
    this.gridControl1[3, 2].CellValue = "True";

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSyfY.png)
[Sample Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwk9nUFE3rlxRTM2LVJOSUlJS3c/view?usp=sharing)

Note
If you have any other queries regarding Syncfusion controls, please consider creating a [support ticket](https://www.syncfusion.com/support/directtrac/) or [posting in the forums](https://www.syncfusion.com/forums).